# How to access an image from its tag?

Tags: android-studio

Let's say we created a button. On click, this button will call a function called image. So we type:

```
public void image(View view){
}
```

Now, we want to access an image from its tag, and store it in a variable. One way to do that is to type:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) view;
img.getTag()
```

But it will cause a stack trace because it will be an AppCompactButton. So how can we access an imageview from its tag?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question but if you want to access the ImageView element from inside the function in which you passed the view(image) you need to specify its ID, something like this:-

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findviewById(R.id.image_view_name);
```

If this isn't what you're looking for please elaborate your problem and I'll try my best to help.